# How to make IIS forwarding an URL to a port on the same machine

Tags: iis, binding, jira, iis-6, portforwarding

I have Windows Server 2012 on a cloud on my company which sits behind the company firewall. This firewall only allows connections on port 80 from the public (world) side.

The machine has IIS-6.2 configured with some websites already working on port 80 with specific URLs after the '/'.
I recently installed Atlassian JIRA in there, this application has its own port listening service, at the moment configured to listen on port 8080 (URL as :8080/JIRA).

Since my company firewall is blocking everything appart from port 80, how can i make it in a way that typing on my laptop *"http://[PUBLIC_WIN_SERVER_IP]/JIRA"* would redirect/bind/etc to *"localhost:8080/JIRA"* (localhost being that Windows Server PC with JIRA, not my laptop)

I tried to use URL Rewrite module but all it does is rewrite the URL on my laptop to 127.0.0.1:8080/JIRA, which of course has nothing on it because it tries to open it on my laptop...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add **AJP/1.2 Connector** into JIRA's `server.xml` file:

```
<Connector port="8009" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3" />
```

You also need to configure a worker in IIS for forwarding requests to JIRA. Atlassian has a step by step configurations for JIRA and IIS [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/integrating-jira-applications-with-iis-802593039.html).